# fork a repo in the same namespace with gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

what's the best way to fork a repo in the same namespace? I have one repo that is shared publicly, but I want to fork a repo in the same namespace that is only private to me so I can do some updates without sharing it publicly. Seems that gitlab doesn't allow forking a repo in the same namespace, it also doesn't allow creating a private branch visible to few people. Any alternative solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Projects in the same namespace must have different names and paths, so to fork a project into the same namespace, you need to set a different name and path for the new project at the time of forking.

Also you can make this project [private](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/public_access.html#change-project-visibility). As it is written in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/visibility_and_access_controls.html#configure-project-visibility-defaults):

> Private - Project access must be granted explicitly to each user. If
> this project is part of a group, access is granted to members of the
> group.

So keep in mind that all members of the namespace will still have access to the forked project.